# Is there an algebraic closure for the quaternions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, quaternions

This post is a sequel of: 
[Is the set of quaternions $\mathbb{H}$ algebraically closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/420697/84284)

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/421164/84284) shows that:
1.  $\mathbb{H}$ is algebraically closed for the polynomials of the form $\sum a_r x^r$
2.  **It is not** for the polynomials freely generated by $\mathbb{H}$ and $x$, because $xi+ix-j$ has no root.

*Question*: Is there an algebraic closure (for the case 2)?
If so:   What does it look like?   What's its dimension over $\mathbb{H}$? What's its matrix representations?

Comment: What is a matrix representation of an algebraic closure? You mean, like an algebra representation over a subdivision ring of finite index?

Comment: The "best" theorem I know for any notion of algebraic closure of $\Bbb H$ in terms of free-polynomials $\Bbb H\langle x\rangle$ is this: every polynomial in $\Bbb H\langle x\rangle$ whose *highest degree term is a single monomial* has a root in $\Bbb H$. The polynomial $xi+ix-j$ fails this because the part of degree $1$ has two pieces. But, for example, $xkx+xi+ix-j$ would have a root, since its highest degree is $2$ and it only has $xkx$ in that degree.

Comment: @rschwieb: by matrix representation I mean a representation on a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{H}$.

Comment: @rschwieb: what's the reference for your theorem?  Then, do you think that the closure is finite dimensional?

Comment: I don't even know that it exists, and I have much less chance of knowing if it's finite dimensional over whatever field/division ring you are imagining.

Comment: Sebastien, you want to read [this paper by Lam](http://math.berkeley.edu/~lam/html/quat.ps) on the quaternions for that theorem. It's an awesome paper for anyone interested in the quaternions :)

Comment: It's not clear to me what "an algebraic closure" for the case 2 would mean, exactly.  I presume that it should contain all elements that satisfy "polynomials" in the free product $\mathbb{H} * \mathbb{Z}\langle x \rangle$. Does it need to be a division algebra?  Does every element need to satisfy a "polynomial" over $\mathbb{H}$?

Comment: See [Is the “algebraic closure” of the quaternions, finite dimensional?](http://mathoverflow.net/q/191629/34538) on mathoverflow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think that there can be an associative $\Bbb{R}$-algebra $L$, containing $\Bbb{H}$ as a subring, such that the equation
$$xi+ix=j\qquad(1)$$
has a solution $x\in L$.

Multiplying $(1)$ by $i$ from the left gives us
$ixi+i^2x=ij$, or $ixi-ij=-i^2x$. As $i^2=-1$ and $ij=k$, this reads
$$
x=ixi-k.\qquad(2)
$$
On the other hand multiplying $(1)$ by $i$ from the right gives us
$xi^2+ixi=ji$, and using $i^2=-1, ji=-k$ this yields
$$
x=ixi+k.\qquad(3)
$$
The equations $(2)$ and $(3)$ together imply $k=-k$. As $k$ is a unit of $L$ this implies that $2=0$ in $L$, so $L$ cannot be an extension of $\Bbb{H}$.

Comment: Sorry about being dense. Clearly $-1$ is in the center. I don't need to assume that $L$ is an $\Bbb{R}$-algebra for the argument to work.

Comment: Thank you! Now the natural question is the following: Is there a (non-commutative) polynomial $p$ (called "allowed") having no root on $\mathbb{H}$ such that there is an associative $\mathbb{R}$-algebra $L$ containing $\mathbb{H}$ as a subring and such that $p$ has a root on $L$ ? If no, then $\mathbb{H}$ is "in some sense" algebraically closed, else, what is its "allowed" closure ?

Comment: I'm not sure. $\Bbb{H}$ is in a natural way a subring of $M_2(\Bbb{C})$ with $1\mapsto I_2$, $i\mapsto \pmatrix{i&0\cr0&-i\cr}$, $j\mapsto \pmatrix{0&1\cr-1&0\cr}$. I would try to find a polynomial that has a zero in the ring of 2x2 complex matrices, but does not have one in $\Bbb{H}$.

Comment: Did you find one?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the answer is morally "no." Now, there is a formal closure for which we can solve free polynomials:  As in the case of fields, you take an inductive limit. Let $\Bbb H=R$ be our normed division algebra. Then

$$\overline{R}=\varinjlim_{[L:R]<\infty} L$$

where the inductive system is taken relative to inclusions of algebra extensions $L/R$ of finite dimension over $R$, each of the form

$$L_p=R\{x\}/(p(x))$$

where $p(x)$ is irreducible over $R$ and $R\{x\}$ is the polynomials freely generated as in case ($2$). This certainly has the required property that all polynomials in $R$ have a root in $\overline{R}$, and any other such object has a copy of this inside of it for purely formal reasons.

I note that the directed system so-defined is indeed a directed system--in fact a lattice--so this should go through unless I'm missing something obvious.

rschweib has noted that the result is no longer a division algebra, so this is really not ideal, but the "algebraic closure" property holds, and necessarily it's a minimal ring where this property can hold, so it seems this is the best we can hope for. However we **also** cannot force algebraicness of the result since $R\{x\}/(xi+ix-j)$ doesn't make $x$ algebraic appropriately in the sense that you want to mimic the field case's excellent definition that algebraicness means $F(\alpha)/F$ is finite dimensional as an algebra over $F$, which doesn't hold in this setting.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think that $\overline{R}$ is finite dimensional over $R$?

Comment: I think not, the same way you have the example of $xi+ix-j$ as irreducible of degree $1$, you should be able to construct "polynomials" of arbitrarily high degree which are irreducible.

Comment: If $\overline{R}$ is an associative division algebra over the real, then it must be infinite dimensional, thanks to the [Frobenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras)).

Comment: This would be the hope: that the same plan works for division rings. But there's still an awful lot up in the air. It isn't totally clear that $R\langle x\rangle/(p(x))$ does what we want it to do, or even if it's finite dimensional. $p(x)=xi+ix-j$ is a good example since $R\langle x\rangle/(p(x))$ looks like it might just be $R[x]$. Noncommutativity really throws a lot of wrenches into doing this whole scheme for $R\langle x\rangle$.

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux It looks like $R\langle x\rangle/(p(x))$ does not have to be a division algebra, so it seems unlikely that $\overline{R}$ is a division algebra.

Comment: Still, I guess the inductive system still exists, and indeed $p(x)$ has a root in the quotient ring, so maybe we get a remnant of what we wanted? It's been a while for me too, so I can't remember if the finiteness of the extensions in the inductive system is vital.

Comment: @rschwieb that's to ensure the extension can rightly be called "algebraic," mimicking the fact that $[F(\alpha):F]<\infty\iff a$ is algebraic.

Comment: @AdamHughes Then maybe this really is the brick wall, since $R\langle x\rangle/(xi+ix-j)$ does not make $x$ algebraic, as was hoped.

Comment: @rschwieb Ah yes! Excellent observation. I'll update the answer to a stance on "negative, on these grounds."

Comment: Do we know for sure that the result is not a division algebra?

Comment: @MannyReyes rschweib noted earlier that $R\{x\}/(xi+ix-j)\cong R[x]$ (at least probably), so it lacks an inverse for $x$ (for example).

Comment: @MannyReyes I for one don't have any idea what the proposed limit looks like. Maybe the quotients are all domains and the inductive limit is too? It would seem like a bit of a miracle if the whole thing was a division ring...

Comment: You should be careful about how you define that colimit.  For instance, if you take the diagram to include all injections between such extensions $L$ of $R$, the commutative analogue would be the zero ring for any $R$ that is not already algebraically closed (because it forces all Galois conjugates to be equal).  As in the commutative case, you really want to construct a well-ordered sequence of extensions by induction (and for this reason existence of algebraic closures requires the axiom of choice in general).

Comment: Alternatively, you could take the colimit where the only maps you have are the inclusions $R\to L$ and you allow no maps between different $L$s.  In this case, the commutative analogue will certainly not be a field (and you need to choose a maximal ideal of it to mod out to get an actual algebraic closure), and it is still not obvious to me that the noncommutative version gives a nonzero ring.

Comment: See [Is the “algebraic closure” of the quaternions, finite dimensional?](http://mathoverflow.net/q/191629/34538) on mathoverflow.

Comment: It is also not even obvious to me that $\mathbb{H}\{x\}/(p(x))$ is a nonzero ring for every nonconstant $p$.

Comment: @EricWofsey: What's about if all the terms of $p$ are of the form $a.x^n.b$?  And next, is there a non-trivial closure for such polynomials?

Comment: I think Eric's right. Won't my argument show that we get the zero ring as a quotient ring easily?