# Why a non-field ring cannot be algebraically closed?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

For instance, it seems that any polynomial in tessarines/bicomplex numbers has roots in tessarines.

So, they seem to be more algebraically closed despite being not a field.

On the other hand, split-complex numbers are not algebraically closed, and their algebraic closure seems to be tessarines.

So, why only a field can be algebraically closed?

**UPDATE**
Is there a notion of rings that are algebraically closed except for the polynomials with coefficients that are divisors of zero?

Answer (score 3):

Take a non invertible element $a$, and consider for example the polynomial $ P (X) = aX - e$ where e is the unit element

Comment: Thanks. But is there a notion of rings that are algebraically closed except for the polynomials with coefficients that are divisors of zero?

Comment: @Anixx That seems to be a completely different question. Note that the coefficient $a$ in the polynomial $P(X)$ in this answer is not necessarily a zero-divisor, it's just non-invertible.

Comment: Yes, but algebras that have non-zero-divisor non-invertible elements are intuitively not closed anyway.

Comment: What about division algebras that are not fields (e.g. quaternions)?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1071874/is-there-an-algebraic-closure-for-the-quaternions

Comment: @Anixx I think you need to clarify your question (by editing the question), rather than shifting the goalposts in the comments.

Comment: @AlexKruckman edited

Comment: @saulspatz thanks, I think that part is answered by the link.

Answer (score 0):

For a non-commutative case, we would have to consider non-commutative polynomials?  With indeterminate $X$, for degree $1$ they would look like
$$
a + bXc + dXe + fXg = 0
$$
and quadratics even worse with terms like $aXbXc$.